# How to make a topology out of $N$ that involves convergent / divergent sets.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $N$ be the naturals $1, 2, \dots$  Call a subset $A$ of $N$ convergent if the reciprocal sum $\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a}$ converges.  Similarly call as set divergent if the sum diverges.  Notice that in this context, since it involves only positive numbers, a set is either convergent or divergent.

Define a topology on $N$ by defining the closed sets to be convergent sets. Clearly arbitrary intersections are convergent as well.  Let $A, B$ be two convergent sets, then $A \cup B$ is also a convergent set. Does this mean that the open sets are precisely the divergent sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $A = \{ 2n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and $B = \{ 2n-1 : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Note that $B = \mathbb{N} \setminus A$, and both $\sum_{a \in A} \frac{1}{a}$ and $\sum_{b \in B} \frac{1}{b}$ diverge. Therefore neither $A$ nor $B$ are convergent sets, and so by definition of the topology they are not closed. As a set is open iff its complement is closed, it follows that their complements, $B$ and $A$, respectively, are not open. (So we have two divergent sets which are not open.)

On the other hand every open set (except for $\emptyset$) must be divergent, simply because if $B \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ were a nonempty open convergent set, then $\mathbb{N} \setminus B$ is a closed set distinct from $\mathbb{N}$, and so it must be convergent, and so $\mathbb{N}$ is the union of two convergent sets, which contradicts that $\mathbb{N}$ is not convergent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean their complements are not closed?

Comment: @EnjoysMath I've added a bit more explanation to my answer.

Comment: Okay, so you exhibited two sets that are neither open nor closed?

Comment: Okay, so $B$ is a divergent set yet not open.

Comment: Okay, so all open sets in the topology are divergent but not all divergent sets are open.